# Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString() in android studio

Tags: android, json, android-studio, post

I'm trying to send a jsonObject to a web server using POST request method with android studio. In some cases it works fine, but in others I get this error:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()
```

If I reduce the JSON size it works fine.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
  URL url;
  HttpURLConnection connection = null;
  url = new URL("MYURL");
  connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

  OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
  BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

  bufferedWriter.write("idUser=" + idUser + "&myJsonArray=" + finalobjectCopy + "&act=backupDados_V2&data=" + currentDateandTime);
  bufferedWriter.flush();
  bufferedWriter.close();
  outputStream.close();

  connection.connect();
```

(I can't upload my JSON)

According to this [website](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) my JSON is ok

How can I fix this and what doase this error mean?

Edit:

If I try to send the JSON using Insomnia it works fine. So the problem is on the android side.

Edit_2:

After several attempts, I found that the problem is in the text I am trying to pass as JSON.
The text was copied by a user from a web page and must have something blocking the correct formation of the JSON.

I have alleready tryed this:

```
 myString = myString.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");

 // erases all the ASCII control characters
 myString = myString.replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]", "");
```

But the problem is the same. I am 95% sure the problem is the text that was copied. Is there any way to get around this situation?

The copied text is from this page:

http://www.aquarismopaulista.com/hemigrammus-erythrozonus/

Comment: It seems response's JSON is too large and somewhere you are trying to get it as string and because of its size, it throws `StackOverflowException`. It would be better if you add all of stacktrace.

Comment: Also just as a suggestion you could consider using `Retrofit` which might handle the case for you, instead of using the `HttpUrlConnection` class